# How do I rebuild a form using AJAX?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I'm trying to create an AJAX controller to rebuild an existing form. It's in the Poll module.

the module has a builtin AJAX replace controller triggered after at the vote POST.

```
  /**
   * Ajax callback to replace the poll form.
   */
  public function ajaxReplaceForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Embed status message into the form.
    $form = ['messages' => ['#type' => 'status_messages']] + $form;
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Render\RendererInterface $renderer */
    $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
    // Render the form.
    $output = $renderer->renderRoot($form);

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->setAttachments($form['#attached']);

    // Replace the form completely and return it.
    return $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('.poll-view-form-' . $this->poll->id(), $output));
  }
```

What I want to do is a similar controller I trigger to (re)build the form on page load (I'm dealing with varnish/poll trouble) and replace the container.

I have no idea how to do it right.

Comment: I'have found some lead https://www.drupal.org/node/2833416

Comment: So far, you stated facts, without asking any explicit question. (The question title doesn't count as explicit question.) You need to tell us what you don't understand, what you tried and what you obtained, etc.

Comment: score shark alert ! >>> What I --want to do-- need is a similar ++AJAX++ controller --I trigger-- to (re)build the form on ++DOM++ page load and replace the container.  <<< I'm to dumb to be more precise

Comment: PS: you have removed the fact that I'm noob in D8, it's too bad because it gives a clue on my current level on my D8 understanding.

Comment: We are all newbie with Drupal 8, if we aren't one of the core maintainers, which I would take answer rather than asking questions. Being a newbie is irrelevant for the question and  future readers, but it can suite a comment.